# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'celery.task.sets'

Tags: python-3.x, celery

So I'm trying to run `from celery.task.sets import subtask` but keep getting the following error: `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'celery.task.sets'`

Celery is definitely installed, I'm using Python 3. What could be the problem?

Comment: The problem is in PYTHONPATH. Python does not know where to look for celery.task.sets. The directory containing the top level package (`celery`) should be in the PYTHONPATH. Considering that Celery (project) has no `celery.task.sets` I am assuming that is your module where you keep your tasks. If I may say, it is a very bad choice for package names considering that Celery has `celery.task` too.

Comment: did you solve this problem